# How to do fuzzy search in Solr for multiple 3 or more spell errors in a single term?

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I have following field type

```xml
<fieldType name="nameprefix" class="solr.TextField"  positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Fuzzy search does not work for 3 or more spell errors .

For eg: querying `"checkers"` using search term `"chockkors ~0.1"` does not return any result. Even on the exact term.
I am using **Solr 5.1.0**.

Comment: did you tried it in solr admin UI?

Comment: try "chockkors ~3" and also "chockkors ~N" depending on your situation.

Comment: @abhijit , yes I tried in admin UI .

Comment: @userMadhav it does not work. It is meant for finding two words in a query within that distance.